# azure linux waagent not running after provisioning

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I'm using AZURE arm for provisioning of UBUNTU images from the VM gallery.

In my template I deploy the image and docker extension. The template worked fine until recently. Now, after deployment of the machine, any extensions fail to install.

```
VM 'hsvnd1wl' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.
```

I checked the machine and the WAAGENT isn't running on the machine (it's installed however). Also the portal instructs me to install the agent.

When I start the agent using

```
#sudo service walinuxagent start
```

The portal reports everything is OK. After redeployment the extension provisioning succeeds.

Any idea on how to debug this or what might be wrong would be much appreciated.

Important parameter values:

```
Ubuntu SKU: 14.04.2-LTS
ApiVersion: 2015-05-01-preview
```

See the template resources below:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('AppVmEthernetName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('ApiVersion')]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('VmEthernetSubnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('ApiVersion')]",
      "name": "[variables('AppVmName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', '/', variables('AppVmEthernetName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('AppVmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[variables('AppVmHostName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('VmAdminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('VmAdminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('AppVmImagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('AppVmImageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('AppVmUbuntuVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "osdisk",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat('https://', parameters('StorageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/vhds', '/',variables('AppVmDiskName'),'.vhd')]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('AppVmEthernetName'))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('AppVmName'),'/', 'DockerExtension')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('ApiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('AppVmName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "DockerExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": { 
          "compose": {
            "weblogic": {
              "image": "caioquirino/weblogic:12c",
              "ports": [ "7001:7001", "7002:7002"],
              "environment": {
                "DOMAIN_NAME": "default"
              },
              "volumes": [
                "/oracle/weblogic/domains:/weblogic/domains"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

## UPDATE 1:

Log output below. When I log to the machine after failed provisioning, the docker is provisioned including the image. I can WGET the resource on the storage and the DNS names are resolved OK.

I don't see any reason for this error to be happening.

```
15:02:30 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno -2] Name or service not known, args:(-2, 'Name or service not known')
15:02:30 ERROR:Retry=2
15:02:30 ERROR:HTTP Req: HEAD https://somestorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/wldisk.495ed12f-5b2b-496d-8e35-04d792f3edf3.status?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=signature_here&sp=rw
15:02:30 ERROR:HTTP Req: Data=None
15:02:30 ERROR:HTTP Req: Header={'x-ms-version': '2014-02-14', 'x-ms-date': '2015-12-11T15:00:09Z'}
15:02:30 ERROR:HTTP Err: response is empty.
15:03:20 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno -2] Name or service not known, args:(-2, 'Name or service not known')
15:03:20 ERROR:Can't get status blob type.
15:03:20 ERROR:Unknown blob type: None
15:04:25 ERROR:Socket IOError [Errno -2] Name or service not known, args:(-2, 'Name or service not known')
15:04:25 ERROR:Retry=0
15:04:25 ERROR:HTTP Req: HEAD https://somestorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/wldisk.495ed12f-5b2b-496d-8e35-04d792f3edf3.status?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=signature_here&sp=rw
15:04:25 ERROR:HTTP Req: Data=None
15:04:25 ERROR:HTTP Req: Header={'x-ms-version': '2014-02-14', 'x-ms-date': '2015-12-11T15:03:45Z'}
15:04:25 ERROR:HTTP Err: response is empty.
15:04:50 ERROR:Traceback (most recent call last):
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 5938, in main
15:04:50 ERROR:    WaAgent.Run()
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 5540, in Run
15:04:50 ERROR:    goalState.ExtensionsConfig.ReportHandlerStatus()
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 3831, in ReportHandlerStatus
15:04:50 ERROR:    UploadStatusBlob(uri, status.encode("utf-8"))
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 2890, in UploadStatusBlob
15:04:50 ERROR:    blobType = GetBlobType(url)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 2819, in GetBlobType
15:04:50 ERROR:    }, chkProxy=True);
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 2758, in HttpHead
15:04:50 ERROR:    return self.HttpRequest("HEAD", url, None, headers, maxRetry, chkProxy)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 2750, in HttpRequest
15:04:50 ERROR:    headers, proxyHost, proxyPort)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 2678, in _HttpRequest
15:04:50 ERROR:    conn.request(method, path, data)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 979, in request
15:04:50 ERROR:    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in _send_request
15:04:50 ERROR:    self.endheaders(body)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
15:04:50 ERROR:    self._send_output(message_body)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 839, in _send_output
15:04:50 ERROR:    self.send(message_body)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in send
15:04:50 ERROR:    self.sock.sendall(data)
15:04:50 ERROR:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 326, in sendall
15:04:50 ERROR:    amount = len(data)
15:04:50 ERROR:TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
15:04:50 ERROR:
15:04:50 ERROR:Exception: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the waagent log from /var/log/waagent.log. and the extension logs from /var/log/azure/.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the waagent logs, unfortunately it didn't shed any light on the problem, for some reason machine fails to connect to the azurestorage (at least that's how I read the log)

Comment: waagent crashed because of the network issue. Could you provide the version of waagent by `waagent -version`? And which template do you use? Azure quickstart template or your private template?

Comment: WALinuxAgent-2.0.13 running on Ubuntu, I'm using private template based on quickstart template. You can see the template above. Wondering how to narrow down the network issue.